# How to execute Snowflake Stored Procedure from Python?

Tags: python-3.x, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created stored procedure in snowflake which is executed fine in snowflake UI and also from server by using snowsql. Now I want to execute procedure from python program, I tried to execute from python, here are the steps that I have followed:

1. establish the connection to snowflake ( successfully able to connect.)

> cs = ctx.cursor()

2. Used appropriate role,warehouse,database and schema.
3. tried to execute procedure like this:

```js
cs.execute("call test_proc('value1', 'value2')")   
x = cs.fetchall() 
print(x)
```

But getting an erorr:

> snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 002140 (42601): SQL
> compilation error: Unknown function test_proc

Can you please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

When connecting to Snowflake using [Python connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html) you could define `DATABASE/SCHEMA`

```
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
                user=USER,
                password=PASSWORD,
                account=ACCOUNT,
                warehouse=WAREHOUSE,
                database=DATABASE,
                schema=SCHEMA
                );
```

Once you have it set up, you could call your stored procedure without using fully-qualified name:

```
cs.execute("call test_proc('value1', 'value2')");
```

---

Alternative way is:

> [Using the Database, Schema, and Warehouse](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#using-the-database-schema-and-warehouse)
>
> Specify the database and schema in which you want to create tables. Also specify the warehouse that will provide resources for executing DML statements and queries.
>
> For example, to use the database testdb, schema testschema and warehouse tiny_warehouse (created earlier):
>
> ```
> conn.cursor().execute("USE WAREHOUSE tiny_warehouse_mg")
> conn.cursor().execute("USE DATABASE testdb_mg")
> conn.cursor().execute("USE SCHEMA testdb_mg.testschema_mg")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have to have command like this

> cs.execute("call yourdbname.schemaname.test_proc('value1', 'value2')")

and It is working as expected.

Thanks

Comment: Had you connected to the DB and schema in your connection string, your first attempt would've worked, as well.